# Single Keyboard Maestro keyboard macro, but different action depending on active application?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

In Keyboard Maestro I want to create a list of keyboard shortcuts, and then under each keyboard shortcut an action to be performed on a per-app basis if that application is active.

For example, when I press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>, I always want to switch to the tab to the left.

I want this action to apply in Chrome, Safari, Xcode, and other apps. The actions in each app ***may have different menu bar item names***, but I want to save them as a single Keyboard Maestro macro for easier grouping.

The *Select or Show a Menu Item* action menu item titles I need to activate are:

- Chrome: "Select Previous Tab"
- Safari: "Show Previous Tab"

[image: Keyboard Maestro window]

But when I set up Keyboard Maestro as seen in the screenshot, this activates *all* of the actions. Regardless of which app is active, both Chrome and Safari run that action.

How can I set it so that only the active application performs the action, *and* give it a list of all possible application/action pairs?

Answer (score 2):

A fairly simple solution: `if-then-else` actions. See this one for Finder:
[image: A Keyboard Maestro if-then-else action that only works if Finder is at the front.]

If you nest each application-specific action within an `If` statement that checks whether the relevant app is at the front, it should work.

Comment: That said, I do something similar, but I keep the different actions within different folders that activate only for the relevant application. That way the within-macro `If` statement isn't necessary. I assume the macros will run faster that way than if you have a large number of statements to check before Keyboard Maestro acts.

Comment: Yeah, that's too much overhead and manual work to set up `if` conditions *and* actions for each. Your folder workflow sounds better. I wonder too if there is a "run first action that completes successfully, then exit" construct.

Comment: I wouldn't think so, as I think the macro checks and completes items linearly, top-down. You could put in a `Cancel This Macro` action at the end of each `If` check, which would end it at the first one that completed—it would just still have to run down the list until it reached one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard Maestro has an Action Category "Front Browser Control" that can be used to send generic commands to web browsers.

I believe my original question/problem still has value, and this answer does not properly solve it, but I was able to use the following commands to fix my immediate issue with the subtle differences between Safari and Chrome:

Actions:

- "Previous Front Browser Tab"
- "Next Front Browser Tab"

[image: Front Browser Control]